# How do i get array of dictionary's 2nd value from JSON response, in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, image, dictionary

**This is my JSON response in postman:**

```
 {
"result": {
    "reviewcat": [
        { 
            "id": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 6
        },
        {
            "id": 7
        }
    ],
    "reviewDet": {
    
        "review_details": [
            {
                "review_point": "2.0"
            },
            {
                "review_point": "4.5"
            },
            {
                "review_point": "3",
            }
        ],
```

*for above response i have created model like below*

```
public class BuyerReviewModel {
public var result : BuyserReviewResult?
}
public class BuyserReviewResult {
public var reviewcat : Array<Reviewcat>?
public var reviewDet : ReviewDet?
}
public class Reviewcat {
public var review_name : String?
public var id : Int?
}
public class ReviewDet {
public var review_details : Array<Review_details>?
}
public class Review_details {
public var review_cat_id : Int?
public var review_point : Float?

}
```

**code:** with this code i am getting only first review `review_point` val 2.5...how do i get 2nd `review_point value 4.5` how?, could anybody guide me

```
class PostReviewVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var rateImageViews: [UIImageView]!// 5 images array
    @IBOutlet var rateButtons: [UIButton]!// 5 buttons array
    var rateFatched: Float = 0.0

    private var testData = ReviewModel(dictionary: NSDictionary()){
        didSet{
            
            titleLbl.text = byuReviewData?.result?.enquiry?.comments
            idLbl.text = byuReviewData?.result?.enquiry?.ref_no
            userNameLbl.text = "\(byuReviewData?.result?.reviewDet?.get_to_user?.first_name ?? "") \(byuReviewData?.result?.reviewDet?.get_to_user?.last_name ?? "")"
            
            if let data = testData?.result?.reviewDet{
                
                for buyReviewData in data.review_details ?? []{
                    
                    rateFatched = buyReviewData.review_point ?? 0.0
                    
                    if rateFatched == NSString("2.5").floatValue{
                        for button in rateButtons {
                            if button.tag >= 2 {
                                allImages[button.tag].image = (#imageLiteral(resourceName: "staremp"))
                            }
                            else {
                                allImages[button.tag].image = (#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star"))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: @burnsi, i have already changed `review_point ` value from string to float

Comment: how to get second `review_point` value

Comment: @burnsi, i am not getting null... how to get the second value... i am unable to get

Comment: @burnsi, no no... the float value working fine... but how to get `review_details` 2nd `review_point `value.. could you guide... its array of dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241615/discussion-between-swiftdev-and-burnsi).

Comment: It's an array, what is the issue with accessing an array?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, how to get array's second `review_point` value

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, with my above code i am able to get only arrays first `review_point ` value

Comment: Yes you have already said that many times. To me it looks from the screenshot like you need to loop over the `reviewcat` array and create a row in your UI for each element and where you get the ReviewDet element by matching the id of the category with the review_cat_id of the detail element.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, i am not using tableview for my UI.. i have used stackview with button and image

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, do i need to use tableview for my UI?

Comment: I don't think that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main issue here seems to be how to get the correct data to display  here is solution that focus on that but ignores any UI related stuff since I consider it off-topic.

I did some changes to the structure but nothing major, changed from class to struct, removed some optionals that didn't make sense and changed from var to let but feel free to change it back since it isn't really important to the answer.

```
public struct BuyserReviewResult {
    public let reviewcat : [Reviewcat]
    public let reviewDet : ReviewDet?
}

public struct Reviewcat {
    public let review_name : String
    public let id : Int
}

public struct ReviewDet {
    public let review_details : [Review_details]
}

public struct Review_details {
    public let review_cat_id : Int
    public let review_point : Float
}
```

Now you can simply get each category name and the points for that category by doing

```
for category in result.reviewcat {
    let points = result.reviewDet?.review_details
        .first(where: { $0.review_cat_id == category.id })?.review_point ?? 0.0
    print(category.review_name, points)
}
```

Note that also ignored the top level type here since it is no longer needed once you have parsed the data.

Comment: how to print first point separately? and second separately?

Comment: o/p now able to print like this Clarity In Specification 2.5 Communication 2.5
Professionalism 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `review_point` is of type `String` and not `Float`, as suggested by [@burnsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6950415/burnsi)

After getting the string value you can always `parse` it to Float